# Cannot install Plugin: Vafpress Post Formats UI

Tags: wordpress

When I install Vafpress Post Formats UI on wordpress, happen:

```
Installing Plugin: Vafpress Post Formats UI
Downloading install package from http://flatlayers.com/required-plugins/vafpress-post-formats-ui-develop.zip…

Unpacking the package…

The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like automatic installer does not work - maybe the Plugin files are broken or your server does not allow this type of zip format.

Try to install the Plugin manually:

http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/wordpress/templates-themes-plugins/how-to-install-wordpress-plugins-manually/